# “I often go into town with Sammy DURING the school holidays.” Why is 'on' impossible here?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Could you explain the use of preposition 'during' in the sentence:

> I often go into town with Sammy during the school holidays

**Question:**
Can anyone explain why 'on' here is grammatically impossible?

My idea is this: we can certainly say 'on a rainy/sunny day, on a schoolday' but not 'on the school holidays' - why is that?

Comment: Are you asking about "during" or "on?

Comment: Hmmm.. your title is different.

Comment: @BillJ I am asking to explain why 'during' is correct while 'on' is incorrect

Answer (score 3):

When "the school holidays" is understood to be a span of time, **during** can be used and **on**, which requires a firm landing place, a spot, not a duration, cannot.

> Bears hibernate during the winter.
>
> Bears hibernate on the winter. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

In temporal contexts, the object of preposition **on** must be a single *place* in time (or a set of single places in time).

> She visits her grandmother on Tuesday.
>
> She visits her grandmother on Tuesdays.
>
> She visits her grandmother on the summer. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Tuesday refers there to a particular location in the week, not to a duration of time.

> The train departs on the hour.

There **hour** is understood not as a duration or span of sixty minutes but as a *point* in the day, a point which we reach every sixty minutes, like inch-markers on a ruler. Just as we can understand an inch either as a span or as a mark on a ruler or yardstick, we can understand *hour* as either a duration or as a point in time along the length of the day.

The flip side of the coin is that **during** cannot be used with single places in time, since it needs a duration, not a point in time:

> She visits her grandmother during Tuesday. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> She visits her grandmother during lunch-hour on Tuesdays.

But it is also possible to understand **lunch-hour** as time-being-spent-in-a-particular-manner, analogous to a journey or a vacation, which allow use of either **during** or **on**:

> She visits her grandmother on her lunch-hour on Tuesdays.
>
> She visits her grandmother during her lunch-hour on Tuesdays.
>
> What did you do during your vacation? <sup>in the time you were away</sup>
>
> What did you do on your vacation? <sup>on the occasion of being away</sup>

So, which preposition to choose depends on whether the noun phrase in question is generally understood to be a point in time, a duration of time, or an occasion that occupies time and thus admits either sense.

Answer (score 1):

A *person* may be **on** holidays. eg.:

> I'll be going to town when I'm on school holidays.

**During** the holiday is a sub-set of the holiday time. eg.:

> I'll be going to town during school holidays.

One goes to a destination **for** holidays. eg.:

> I'll be going to Hawaii for the next school holidays because the town is boring.

(Sorry. Prepositions aren't really logical.)